# SDL_UpdateTexture are raw pixels copied?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have an array of pixels that I display to the screen.
To do that I use an SDL_Texture object that gets updated using SDL_UpdateTexture like this:

```
SDL_UpdateTexture(frame_buffer_texture, nullptr, &frame_buffer_pixels, screen_res_x);
```

In the documentation it says the the third argument is a pointer to an array of pixels however it doesn't specify if the pixels are copied or not.

Is it okay to use a local variable with the pixels that goes out of scope after SDL_UpdateTexutre like this:

```
void function()
{
    uint32_t pixels[screen_res_x * screen_res_y] = { /* pixel data here */ }
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, nullptr, &pixels, screen_res_x);
}
```

or do I have to allocate memory for the pixels on the stack like this:

```
void function()
{
    delete pixels; // Delete old pixels

    pixels = new uint32_t[screen_res_x * screen_res_y];
    // Set pixels values here..

    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, nullptr, pixels, screen_res_x);
}
```

Not sure if this matters but here is how I render the texture to the screen:

```
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nullptr, nullptr);

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

and here is how it is created:

```
SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, screen_res_x * screen_res_y)
```

Comment: They are copied. "Textures" should be stored in video memory (as opposed to "surfaces" stored in RAM), so the data must be copied.

Answer (score 0):

What `SDL_UpdateTexture` does exactly depends on the renderer, but for reference, [the OpenGL renderer](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/3472dc11d6f7d22055d185724853c4dfcc0e3967/src/render/opengl/SDL_render_gl.c#L684) calls glTexSubImage2D and [the software renderer](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/3472dc11d6f7d22055d185724853c4dfcc0e3967/src/render/software/SDL_render_sw.c#L125) does a memcpy.

> do I have to allocate memory for the pixels on the stack like this

`new` allocates on the *heap*. An array like `uint32_t pixels[screen_res_x * screen_res_y]` is allocated on the stack. But to answer your actual question: no, you do not need to keep the pixel data alive after the call to `SDL_UpdateTexture`, so you do not need to do a dynamic allocation (on the heap).

However, I would add that if you plan on allocating an array of `uint32_t` the size of your screen, you might want to do a dynamic allocation regardless. Assuming `uint32_t` is 4 bytes and your screen size is 1920x1080, that's `1920*1080*4 = 8294400` bytes to allocate. A typical stack size can vary from a few KB to a few MB, so you can easily try to allocate more than your stack allows.